# Trying to return new arrays based on initial array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array of vehicles that are available to buy on a company website. Within the van array there is a nested array that contains the model and the vehicle value.

```
{vanNumber: "7654628", vanDescription: "VW Campervan", value: {make: "VW", amount: 11660}}
{vanNumber: "9873093", vanDescription: "Renault Campervan", value: {make: "Renault", amount: 3429}}
{vanNumber: "1739566", vanDescription: "Nissan Campervan", value: {make: "Nissan", amount: 5600}}
{vanNumber: "3949219", vanDescription: "VW", value: {make: "VW", amount: 1960}}
```

I'm trying to return an array for each car brand and the total value of each individual brand. I already have the addition part working but I'm trying to loop through the array and return a new array for each car manufacturer.

So in this example, I would like to return a VW array that contains the two VW vehicles based on the value.make value and two other arrays, one for the Nissan and one for the Renault.

I was **previously returning the array like this** (see below)

```
// returns an array of VW vehicles when make = VW
 if (vanMake != undefined) {
        let result = vanMake.filter((x) => {
            return x.value.make === 'VW';
        });

        return result
   }
```

But if I added 3000 cars to the array, **I'd like to return a new array to the view for each manufacturer and the total value of each car under that make without having to do an if else for every car brand**.

```
export function toTotalVanValue(state: fromVans.State): any {

let vanMake = state.vans.vanDetails.vehicle;

        //prints out the array of objects 
        console.log('vanMake', vanMake);

        if (vanMake != undefined) {
            let result = vanMake.filter((x) => {
                let make = x.value.make;
                if (make) {
                    console.log ('make', make);
                    return make
                }
                return x.value.make;
            });
            result.forEach(function(element) {
                vanMake.filter((x) => {
                    console.log('x.value.make', x.value.make);
                    return x.value.make;
                });

              //prints out each element individually
                console.log('element element', element);
              });

        //prints out the array of objects 
            console.log('result', result);
            return result
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the EXACT structure that you're looking for but you can use `collection.reduce` to consolicate your colllection into the value that you want.

```js
const vehicles = [
  {
    vanNumber: "7654628",
    vanDescription: "VW Campervan",
    value: {
      make: "VW",
      amount: 11660
    }
  }, {
    vanNumber: "9873093",
    vanDescription: "Renault Campervan",
    value: {
      make: "Renault",
      amount: 3429
    }
  }, {
    vanNumber: "1739566",
    vanDescription: "Nissan Campervan",
    value: {
      make: "Nissan",
      amount: 5600
    }
  }, {
    vanNumber: "3949219",
    vanDescription: "VW",
    value: {
      make: "VW",
      amount: 1960
    }
  }];

const results = vehicles.reduce((accumalator, current) => {
  const { make } = current.value;
  console.log(make);
  if (accumalator[make]) {
    accumalator[make].push(current);
    return accumalator;
  }

  accumalator[make] = [current];
  return accumalator;
}, {});

console.log(Object.keys(results));
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach that solves this kind of problem is, as so often, based on [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) ...

```js
var vehicleList = [
  {vanNumber: "7654628", vanDescription: "VW Campervan", value: {make: "VW", amount: 11660}},
  {vanNumber: "9873093", vanDescription: "Renault Campervan", value: {make: "Renault", amount: 3429}},
  {vanNumber: "1739566", vanDescription: "Nissan Campervan", value: {make: "Nissan", amount: 5600}},
  {vanNumber: "3949219", vanDescription: "VW", value: {make: "VW", amount: 1960}}
];

function collectAndGroupVehicleItemByBrand(collector, vehicleItem) {
  var
    list  = collector.list,
    index = collector.index,
    make  = vehicleItem.value.make,
    group;

  if (make in index) {
    group = index[make];
  } else {
    group = index[make] = { make: make, count: 0, list: [] };
    list.push(group);
  }
  group.count = group.list.push(vehicleItem);

  return collector;
}

var dictionary = vehicleList.reduce(collectAndGroupVehicleItemByBrand, {

  list  : [],
  index : {}

});

console.log('groupedVehicleList   : ', dictionary.list);
console.log('groupedVehicleIndex  : ', dictionary.index);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```